# Passing parameters to an object on construction

Tags: scala

An `object` needs to hold a globally available cache. In order to initialize the cache, the object needs to be passed a variable obtained from a third party framework running within the application.

As objects do not take constructor parameters, how is it possible to pass the variable from the framework to the object so that it is available during object construction?

A workaround would be to have an init method on the object (which accepts the third party framework variable), and add some scaffolding code. However, is there a better way?

Comment: "objects do not take constructor parameters ... available during object construction" - Did you just say this was impossible and then ask how to do it in the same sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm so i would not recommend writing a cache yourself. There are libraries that do the job better. There is this Scala project called `Mango` that wraps the excellent Java based `Guava` library that gives caching abilities.

You could write code like this(From the documentation) ,

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import org.feijoas.mango.common.cache._

// the function to cache
val expensiveFnc = (str: String) => str.length  //> expensiveFnc  : String => Int 

// create a cache with a maximum size of 100 and 
// exiration time of 10 minutes
val cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
.maximumSize(100)
.expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
.build(expensiveFnc)              //> cache  : LoadingCache[String,Int]

cache("MyString")  //
```

Also there is a simple library called `ScalaCache` that is excellent at this.
[Check it here](https://github.com/cb372/scalacache)   This works only with Scala 2.11 onwards because the use of macros.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you don't put mutable state on an `object`. But if you really need to, you could put a `var` field on it.

```
object TheObject {
    var globalMutableState: Option[TheStateType] = None
}
```

Whatever needs to set that state can do so with an assignment.

```
TheObject.globalMutableState = Some(???)
```

And whatever needs to refer to it can do so directly.

```
TheObject.globalMutableState.get
```